# Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type _ found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for_ may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

I am utilizing this view to validate and upload the object of type "event" to Firebase. After completion, my objective is to incorporate the newly created event into the array of events in my "profileViewModel." This step is crucial for updating the UI with the new event seamlessly, eliminating the need for manual feed refresh. Unfortunately, I am encountering an error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ProfileViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ProfileViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view."

here is my eventFinalPage:

```
import SwiftUI

struct EventFinalPage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var newEventViewModel: EventPostViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel
    @State private var showEventDetails = false
    @State private var isPostSuccessful = false
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
//    @Binding var tabIndex: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                
                headerButtons()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text(newEventViewModel.EventTitle)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.leading, 8)
                
                
                if let profileImage = newEventViewModel.selectedImage{
                    Image(uiImage: profileImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity
                               
                        )
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                }
                
                else {
                    
                    Image("hey")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(maxWidth: 150, maxHeight: 150)
                        .padding()
                }
                
                HStack(spacing: 16){
                    NavigationLink{
                        AddEventLink()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "link")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    }
                    Button{
                        showEventDetails.toggle()
                    }
                label: {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.clock")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showEventDetails) {
                    EventDetails()
                }
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                .padding(.leading, 8)
                .padding(.top, 4)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                
                HStack{
                    TextEditor(text: $newEventViewModel.EventDescription)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            if(newEventViewModel.isLoading){
                CustomProgressView()
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(profileViewModel)
    }
}


extension EventFinalPage {
    private func headerButtons() -> some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button{
                Task{
                    guard let eventPost = try await newEventViewModel.uploadPost(caption: newEventViewModel.EventDescription) else {return}
                    profileViewModel.addNewEvent(event: eventPost)
//                    tabIndex = 0
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    newEventViewModel.EventTitle = ""
                    newEventViewModel.Thumbnail = []
                    newEventViewModel.selectedImage = nil
                    newEventViewModel.EventLink = ""
                    newEventViewModel.EventDescription = ""
                    newEventViewModel.isLoading = false
                }
             
                

            }label:{
                Text("Post")
                    .bold()
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.vertical,8)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                
            }
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get this code to work right here in the extension of eventFinalPage:

```
   profileViewModel.addNewEvent(event: eventPost)
```

Here is my profileViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
@MainActor
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userEvents = [Event]()
    @Published var userPosts = [Tweet]()
    private let service = ProfileService()
    
    init(){
        Task{
            try await fetchEvents()
            try await fetchPosts()
        }
    }
    func addNewEvent(event: Event) {
        userEvents.insert(event, at: 0)
    }
    
        func fetchEvents() async throws {
}
....
```

My profileViewModel is being created in another view called ProfileView.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var profileUpdateviewModel: ProfileUpdateViewModel
    @StateObject var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel()
```

Comment: In SwiftUI you are supposed to use `View` structs, not your own view model objects. Also, in SwiftUI you must use `.task`, not `Task {}` otherwise the lifetime won't be correct.